# SQL Query for multiple fields

Tags: sql, oracle11g, multiple-columns

I have a small list (<200) Person_IDs which I have sitting in a .csv file.  I would like to build a query that will search my Oracle 11G Database Person Table and pull specific information for each individual in one swoop.  Example:  I need name, dob & address.
I've never written a query like this before, and wondering what is the best approach.

Any tips are welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: The best approach is to begin by reading documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm

Comment: I've used the IN clause, which works well, but it's not exactly a nice way of doing it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong about using IN.

Comment: I figured there come be some other way to make a cleaner statement. 200 p_ids in closed brackets sitting next to an IN isn't ideal, works fine though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the "IN" approach will do.  I was however hoping for a cleaner method.